# Why is OpenCV python crashing in Windows?

Tags: python, opencv, crash

I am running **OpenCV2.2** on **Windows 7 64-bit**.

I built **OpenCV** using `cmake` with `MinGW 32-bit`.

I have no problem with the C/C++ build. However the python bindings seem to have some problems. Most of the python samples are crashing.

The `HighGui` functions seem to cause trouble. Python crashes when I try to read an image (`using imread, LoadImage or LoadImageM`), display an image (`imshow or ShowImage`) or even create and manipulate windows (`NamedWindow, MoveWindow,` etc).\

`WaitKey` doesn't crash python but it always returns `a -1` immediately, no matter how long the delay I provide. Similarly `imgproc` functionality listed under "Image Filtering" in the [reference](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/imgproc__image_processing.html) seem to crash python. I haven't been able to test it with too many other functions, mainly because I can't load in images and I am forced to test it with matrices i have built myself.

I am currently using **python 2.6.6 (32-bit)** , but I got the same problem with **python 2.7 (32-bit)**. I also tried building the python wrappers for **OpenCV2.1**, and I got the same problem. It's very likely a problem specific to my setup. I've been cracking my head against this problem for quite some time now, I would appreciate any help.

Thanking you in advance.

Regards,
Anush.

Comment: I am having a similar problems on windows 7 32 bits, latest MinGW. Did you build the c++ sample programs (option available in cmake)? Have you tried running c:\...\OpenCV-2.2.0MinGW\bin\calibration_artificial.exe , or any other exe in that folder? Mine freezes always after opening the window. After a bit of debugging, I came to the conclusion that MoveWindow of the windows API was causing troubles, but I don't know where to go now...

Comment: I can't even get that far, I'm using windows 7 64 bit, with 32 bit python 2.7, numpy 1.5.1, scipy 0.9.0, and MinGW and Cmake. Whenever I try to mingw32-make it errors with: `mingw-make[2]: *** [lib/cv.pyd] Error 1` and `mingw-make[1]: *** [modules/python/CMakeFiles/opencv_python.dir/all] Error 2`

Comment: Is there a valid reason for you to continue working on OpenCV 2.2 ? OpenCV 2.3 python bindings are known to be way more stable http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog. And the last version now is now 2.4 !